# Deriving Partial Differential Equation Solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Anyone can help me? Please. This is for my thesis.

How to derive the solution of
$$u.u_{xy} - u_{x}u_{y} - u_{y} = 0$$ with known $u(0,y)$, $u(0,x)$ and $u(y,y) = 0$

You can state the solution in the form of $u(0,y)$ and $u(0,x)$

The solution is 
$$u(x,y) = \frac{u(0,y) - u(0,x)}{\frac{\partial u(0,x)}{\partial x}}$$

Comment: The solution you state does not satisfy $u(y,y)=1$. Please review the stated problem especially all boundary conditions.

Comment: @maxmilgram I am sorry there is a mistake. I have corrected it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we rewrite the equation as
$$
u^2(u_{xy}u^{-1}-u_xu_yu^{-2}-u_yu^{-2})=u^2(u_xu^{-1}+u^{-1})_y=0
$$
Thus we can integrate with respect to $y$ and get:
$$
u_x(x,y)+1=u(x,y)c(x)
$$
For an arbitrary function $c(x)$. The solution to this ODE can be found by the usual standard methods and reads:
$$
u(x,y)=\frac{f(y)-a(x)}{a'(x)}
$$
For $c(x)=-(\ln(a'(x))'$. Inserting the initial conditions yields the solution.

Comment: I'm sorry sir can I ask you a little bit? First how can you integrate $u^2(u_{x}u^-1+u^-1)_{y}$ and resulting $u_{x}(x,y) + 1 = u(x,y)c(x)$?

Comment: Either $u=0$ or the derivative with respect to $y$ is zero. In the second case the bracket is equal to a "constant" $c(x)$. Constant means that it is not depending on the variable $y$.

Comment: Oke sir I understand. Now the second is, what is the reason behind choosing that c(x) function?

Comment: You don't have to, it just simplifies the solution of the resulting ODE.

Comment: Thank you sir now I understand!

Comment: No problem, if your question is answered, feel free to mark my reply as such.